# How to expand UITableViewCell height in dynamically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a  `UITableView`. In my tableview l I want to dynamically add another view into my cell and expand the cell height. I have seen some examples but those are with `UILabels`. UILabels can changes the height according to the text height. But how can I manually add another view and expand those cells?

Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use the manually calculate the cell height,its easy,after you add another view,you calculate the height,then call reloadData or reloadRowsAtIndexPaths,and return the height in tableview:heightForRowAtIndexPath function.
If you use the auto calculate the cell height.you should let system know how to calculate,you should set the autolayout clearly and completely.You should add the another view`s left、right、top、bottom constraint and the system will auto canculate the height.So the cells will Be expanded.

Comment: Thanks,, for table.rowheight should I set default size or set it to dynamic?

Comment: you can set like this:self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;  //  a value like all the cell
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

Answer (score 0):

You can set cell height by override `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat`

Answer (score 0):

**Implement these two UITableViewDelegate methods:**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // return estimatedHeight
  }
```

**View in your dynamic cell needs to have top, bottom, trailing, leading and height constraints. Setting view height constraint constant will set cell height according to view height.**

**You can have view height constraint property in your dynamic cell:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var customViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

**Constraint constant value can be changed in cellForRowAt:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellId", for: indexPath) as! Cell

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell.customViewHeightConstraint.constant = 100
    case 1:
        cell.customViewHeightConstraint.constant = 200
    case 2:
        cell.customViewHeightConstraint.constant = 300
    case 3:
        cell.customViewHeightConstraint.constant = 400
    default:
        cell.customViewHeightConstraint.constant = 100
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I am doing this  if(arraycontainsthisvalue) then change the heigt=100 else height=50. but sometimes its giving me wrong height when the condition is false its still giving me 100 why is that?